# Docker Error on ECS with EC2 - exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I really need help here as I have tried everything that I can think of.. I have a react JS app docker container built on alpine which runs perfectly on AWS Fargate. However, when I deploy and run the same on EC2 instance with ECS, I a getting this error "exec /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error".

Here is my dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/bash

FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 node:16-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine as production

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Also, when I inspect the container, some key details are below:

"Entrypoint": ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"],

"Architecture": "amd64", "Os": "linux", "Size": 26545012,

I read on some forums that i need to add "#!/bin/bash" to the start of the file docker-entrypoint.sh.. However, this file is auto generated while building the container. So how can I add this line?

I will really appreciate any help..

Comment: Dockerfile is not a bash script, so no, you don't nerd that header. But it's also not the problem... Are you sure you're using AMD64 ECS instance and not Gravitron / ARM?

Comment: I am using AMD64 ECS instance. When I SSH into the EC2 machine, I run the command uname -m, it does confirm x86_64. Also I have removed the #!/bin/bash header in the docker file..

Comment: OneCricktreer; thanks.. actually your input did point me into a direction.. I recreated the container (and EC2)as well as as the image for Linus/ARM64 just to try it out and it did work...